# How to loop through a character array to match array items from one column and extract full rows from a tab separated text file

Tags: bash

I have a tab separated text file with the first column subject ID (characters) another 23 column (all values except the second column which is also characters).

There are 700 rows (subjects), but I want to extract a subset of 200 rows based on matching with the subject ID column.

I have tried using `grep` and `sed` and `awk` with various combinations but I have not been successful. Some things that have failed include:

```
for sub in ${subjects[@]}; do 
  grep $sub | \
  sed < baseline_subs.txt > baseline_moresubs.txt; 
done
```

and

```
awk '{if ($1 == $sub) { print } }' baseline_moresubs.txt
```

Please help

Comment: `awk` is the right way to go but it looks like you are trying to use a shell variable in your awk script, which you can't do. Instead `awk -v sub=$sub '$1 == sub{print $0}' baseline_moresubs.txt`. If that doesn't work, then please share sample data from your file so we can understand better.

Comment: do the 200 lines have 200 unique subject IDs? if 'yes', are those 200 unique subject IDs stored in the `subjects[]` array? if `yes`, please (also) update the question with a sample of the array entries (eg, `declare -p subjects` and show us the first 5-10 entries)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Suggestion 1 `awk` script: scanning `baseline_moresubs.txt` `${#subjects[@]}` times

screen same input file many times, each time screening one subject.

```
for sub in ${subjects[@]}; do 
  # screen baseline_moresubs.txt for 1st field,
  awk "\$1 == \"$sub\" {print}" baseline_moresubs.txt
done
```

#### Suggestion 2 `awk` script: scanning `baseline_moresubs.txt` once

Map `subjects[]` array into `awk` associative array (dictionary) `subjDict`. Than scan each line for any of the subjects.

```
awk -v inpArr="${subjects[@]}" '
BEGIN { # pre processing input
  split(inpArr,arr); # map inpArr into arr indexed 1,2,3...
  for (i in arr) subjDict[arr[i]] = 1; # map arr into dictonary
}
$1 in subjDict{print} # if 1st field in dictionary print line
' baseline_moresubs.txt
```